# What is wrong with how I am approaching this conditional expectation problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> An individual experiences a loss due to property damage and a loss due
>   to bodily injury. Losses are independent and uniformly distributed on the
>   interval $[0,3]$. Calculate the expected loss due to bodily injury, given that at
>   least one of the losses is less than $1$.

This is my reasoning:

Let $X$ be the property damage loss and $Y$ be the bodily injury loss.

The probability that at least one of the losses is less than $1$ is equal to the sum of the following three probabilities:

$$P(X < 1 , Y > 1) + P(X > 1 , Y < 1) + P(X < 1 , Y < 1)$$

From independence

$${1\over 3} \cdot {2\over 3} + {2\over 3} \cdot {1\over 3} + {1\over 3} \cdot {1\over 3} = {5 \over 9}$$

The probability distribution of $Y$ given that at least one of the losses is less than $1$ is the three cases divided by the sum of all the probabilities that at least one of the losses is less than $1$.

$${P(X < 1 , Y > 1)\over {5 \over 9}} ,  {P(X > 1 , Y < 1)\over {5 \over 9}}  ,\  \text{and} \ {P(X < 1 , Y < 1)\over {5 \over 9}}$$

$${{1\over 3} \cdot {2\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}} ,  {{2\over 3} \cdot {1\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}}  ,\  \text{and} \ {{1\over 3} \cdot {1\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}}$$

Finally, the expectation of $Y$ is given by integrating and summing the distributions

$$\int_1^3y{{1\over 3} \cdot {2\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}}dy +  \int_0^1y{{2\over 3} \cdot {1\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}}dy  +  \int_0^1y{{1\over 3} \cdot {1\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}}dy = 1.9$$

However, the correct solution is $1.1$, what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: You have done a fantastic job in first part, calculating the conditional distribution of $Y$ is a mixture: truncated on $(0, 1)$ with probability $3/5$ and truncated on $(1, 3)$ with probability $2/5$. However you still need to compute the density of the two truncated distribution. A truncated uniform is still uniform, so the density of the first one is $1$, but the density of the latter part is $1/2$ which you missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first case the conditional expectation is obviously $2$, in the second $\frac12$ and in the third $\frac12$, making the overall conditional expectation $$2\cdot{{1\over 3} \cdot {2\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}} +  \frac12\cdot{{2\over 3} \cdot {1\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}} +  \frac12\cdot{{1\over 3} \cdot {1\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}} = 1.1 $$

In more detail, as BGM says in a comment, your error was in not using the conditional density in your integrals.  In the first case the conditional distribution is uniform over $[1,3]$ so the density is $\frac{1}{3-1}=\frac12$.  In the second and third cases the conditional distribution is uniform over $[0,1]$ so the density is $\frac{1}{1-0}=1$.  So your expression should have been   $$\int_1^3 y\cdot \frac12 \, dy  \cdot {{1\over 3} \cdot {2\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}} +  \int_0^1 y\cdot 1\, dy \cdot {{2\over 3} \cdot {1\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}} +  \int_0^1 y\cdot 1 \, dy  \cdot {{1\over 3} \cdot {1\over 3}\over {5 \over 9}} = 1.1$$ where each integral gives the conditional expectation for that case

Comment: still don't quite understand why we need to consider distribution of truncated y. Simply by definition of conditional expectation, shouldn't the integrand be $y\cdot $ (conditional density)? where $y$ is the original RV ~ unif(0, 3)

Comment: @MinYoungKim In my final expression the integrands are $y \cdot \frac12$ and $y \cdot 1$ and $y \cdot 1$, each of which is $y$ times the conditional density

Comment: I don't see how that is the conditional density.. Isn't the conditional density here just the fractions like $\frac{1/3*2/3}{\frac{5}{9}}$?

Comment: @MinYoungKim $ {{{1\over 3}\cdot {2\over 3}}\over {5 \over 9}}$ is the probability that $P(X < 1 , Y > 1 \mid \min(X,Y)<1)$.  It is not a density