# $X,Y\sim U[0,5]$ are independent. What is the expectation of $Y$, given at least one of the RVs is less than $1$?

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

How do I approach such a problem without the knowledge of Truncated distributions?

Also, my approach was similar to the person who posted the question:
[What is wrong with how I am approaching this conditional expectation problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966468/what-is-wrong-with-how-i-am-approaching-this-conditional-expectation-problem)

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpful: https://danieltakeshi.github.io/2016/09/25/the-expectation-of-the-minimum-of-iid-uniform-random-variables/

Comment: I can see the similarity of the approach, but I can't see why *you* failed in that approach, and what particular step fell apart. Specifying this would be a far better way of getting a more comprehensive answer to the question. If you are using this platform, you may as well use it to find issues in your working and common errors that you might be making, rather than merely asking for an answer. Next time, if you are posting an attempt please make sure that it's detailed and you highlight *where* you got stuck, and (roughly) *why* you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things you need to know about truncated distributions is that a truncated uniform is uniform and the total probability has to equal $1$ for any distribution.  The rest works just like in the question you cited.

Comment: Okay, so does that mean for U[0,1] and U[1,5], the probabilities are 9/25 and 16/25 respectively in this question?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the definition of conditioning a random variable over an event, followed by the independence of the random variables:

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y\mid X<1\cup Y<1)&=\dfrac{\mathsf E(Y\mathbf 1_{X<1\cup Y<1})}{\mathsf P(X<1\cup Y<1)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf E(Y\mathbf 1_{X<1\cap Y\geq 1}+Y\mathbf 1_{Y<1})}{\mathsf P((X<1\cap Y\geq 1)\cup(Y<1))}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X<1)\,\mathsf E(Y\mathbf 1_{Y\geq 1})+\mathsf E(Y\mathbf 1_{Y<1})}{\mathsf P(X<1)\,\mathsf P(Y\geq 1)+\mathsf P(Y<1)~}\\[1ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$